# Office VBA: When are Properties processed?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I wonder when Properties are processed in Office VBA.

Consider this Class module (`MyClass`):

```vb
Public Property Get ExpensiveProperty() As Variant
    'Some resource expensive procedure here
End Property

Public Property Get SomeProperty() As Variant
    'Something easy
End Property
```

And this Module:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim MC As MyClass
    Set MC = New MyClass
    
    Dim Smth As Variant
    Smth = MC.SomeProperty
End Sub
```

Is `MC.ExpensiveProperty` processed in `test()` procedure? (Assume no reference to `ExpensiveProperty` in `SomeProperty`)

Comment: I don't this so (why should it?), but why don't you check with the debugger?

Comment: When debugging, all properties are computed. So it is not so simple. I'm not sure if there is some trigger (for example: When Property procedure access Range Object it is always processed even if not used <- I made up this condition).

Comment: No, properties are not accessed *when debugging*, properties are accessed when you add the object to the watch window. When simply debugging (by setting a breakpoint), you will see that properties are only entered when you request them. There is no functional difference between a property and a method, so expecting a property to be randomly accessed is no different to expecting all methods to be randomly called, which does not happen.

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks for reply. I received "mysterious" error while debugging, I found it was caused by an unused property. So I was uncertain how it works. But maybe it was called by some forgotten watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a simple `Debug.Print`-Statement reveals that `ExpensiveProperty` is not called except if requested (and I see no point why it should).

```
Public Property Get ExpensiveProperty() As Variant
    Debug.Print "Expensive..."
    ExpensiveProperty = "Expensive"
End Property

Public Property Get SomeProperty() As Variant
    Debug.Print "Easy..."
    SomeProperty = "Easy"
End Property
```

After running your test-routine, you will find the output `Easy...` in the immediate window but not `Expensive...`. Setting a breakpoint in both getter also shows that the expensive method is not called.

Of course that changes if you add a watch on the `MC`-variable or look into it in the `Local`-window. In the moment you click on the small [+]-button, the debugger tries to evaluate all public properties and for that of course must call all getter methods (note that in that case the debugger will not stop at any breakpoint, but the `Debug.Print` is executed.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I received "mysterious" error while debugging, I found it was caused by an unused property. But maybe it was called by some forgotten watch.