# VBA Class module is running code before I ask for it to run

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Usually I can figure out a way to generalize my problem and Google it but I can't even begin to figure out what is happening.

As a disclaimer, I am not a professional programmer. I work in a finance department. I'm just playing around with VBA inside of Excel.

I am trying to learn collections and class modules in VBA and I've run into a really weird problem. So what I'm trying to do is make a program that runs a breadth first search to solve a ball sort puzzle.

So in my module, I run a sub that loads the starting board state into an array I call `field()`. So my current field looks like

```vb
Field ((a,f,d,e),(b,g,d,h),...,(x,x,x,x),(x,x,x,x))
```

Each letter is a string (this is so that I can alphabetized the board state to make sure I'm not repeating the same moves over and over again).

What I want is for when I create a class, it will store the current board, the solution up to that point, and the possible valid moves from that state. The way I achieve this is:

```vb
Sub solvepuzzle()
    Call loadboard 'this handles creating the game board
    
    Dim testboard as variant
    Dim o as New Board
    
    o.ordered = field()
    testboard = o.moves
End sub
```

Board class:

```vb
Private tubes as new collection
Private tempx as integer
Private tempy as integer

Property let ordered(current as variant)
    'This just loads the field into the object. When I step through this it works fine.
    'But when I run it, it seems like it runs the moves property. 
    
    Dim rws as integer
    Dim clms as integer
    Dim i, j as integer
    Dim focus() as variant
    
    rws = Ubound(current,2)
    clms = Ubound(current,1)
    
    For j = 0 to clms
       Redim focus(rws)
       For i = 0 to rws
          Focus(i) = current(j,i)
       Next i
       Tubes.add focus
    Next j 
End property

Property get moves() as collection
    For starttube = 1 to clms
        For endtube = 1 to clms
            If isvalid(starttube, endtube, rws) then

            'Once it has found a valid move it copys the array to an array I Dimmed
            'in the move property, then it removes the array from its spot in the
            'tubes collection. Then it saves the string letter of the chosen ball
            'to a variable, and changes the position in the array to an "x" Since
            'e that is my variable I use for an empty space.
            'Then it replaces the array back where it was in the tubes collection.
    
            'Then it repeats this but for the ending location. It removes the array,
            'and replaces the last "x" with the moving string. And then it inserts it
            'back into the tubes collection.
    
            'I check to see if it is a board state I haven't been to yet in this
            'solution path, then I create a copy of the board inside a different
            'collection and then undo the move. 
    
            'this is as far as I've written.
End property
```

So when I step through the code `ordered` simply places the `field()` array into a tubes collection inside the object. Everything works. However when I run the code, if I set a breakpoint just after it loads the `field()` into tubes, but before I've even left the property, if I check the locals window, tubes now has moved the first string to the location it is first allowed to move to. So it should be `tubes(1) = (a,f,d,e)` and `tubes(10) = (x,x,x,x)` however after I run the code it shows `tubes(1) = (x,f,d,e)` and `tubes(10) = (x,x,x,a)`.

I thought maybe that since it is a class that VBA is trying to prepare the other properties when called for but it shouldn't be keeping that change because in the move property I'm undoing the move. So it should stay the same.

So the problem is that when I step through the code it works perfectly, exactly like I want it to. However when I let it run by the time it hits my breakpoints it has screwed it up and starts doing other moves that I haven't investigated yet.

Thank you for any help. I tried to put in as much of the code as I could. Although I just saw below that it did not format properly but I'm not entirely sure how to fix that. I'll answer any questions I can. I'm just completely stumped.

Here is a code that reproduces the problem.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim field() As Variant
    Dim rws As Integer
    Dim clms As Integer
    Dim o As New Board
    
    rws = 3
    clms = 10
    
    ReDim field(clms, rws)
    
    For i = 0 To clms
        For j = 0 To rws
            field(i, j) = Range("B2").Offset(j, i).Value
        Next j
    Next i
    
    o.ordered = field
End Sub
```

```vb
' Board Class

Private tubes As New Collection
Private alphaorder As String
Private sol As New Collection
Private paststates As New Collection
Private tempx As Integer
Private tempy As Integer

Property Get name() As String
        name = alphaorder
End Property

Property Get moves() As Collection

    Dim rws As Integer
    Dim clms As Integer
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim starttube As Integer
    Dim endtube As Integer
    Dim possible As New Collection
    Dim stringcheck As String
    Dim tuberemove As Variant
    Dim ballcolor As String
    
    rws = UBound(tubes(1), 1)
    clms = tubes.count
    
    For starttube = 1 To clms
    For endtube = 1 To clms
        If isvalid(starttube, endtube, rws) Then
        
            
            tuberemove = tubes(starttube)
            tubes.Remove starttube
            ballcolor = tuberemove(tempx)
            tuberemove(tempx) = "x"
            tubes.Add tuberemove, , starttube
            tuberemove = tubes(endtube)
            tubes.Remove endtube
            tuberemove(tempy) = ballcolor
            tubes.Add tuberemove, , endtube
            
            stringcheck = alphabetize(rws, clms - 1)
            
            For Each x In paststates
                If x = stringcheck Then
                    GoTo failskip
                End If
            Next
            
            possible.Add stringcheck
            possible.Add starttube
            possible.Add tempx
            possible.Add endtube
            possible.Add tempy
            For Each x In tubes
                possible.Add x
            Next
            moves.Add possible
            Set possible = Nothing
            
failskip:
            
            tuberemove = tubes(endtube)
            tubes.Remove endtube
            ballcolor = tuberemove(tempy)
            tuberemove(tempy) = "x"
            tubes.Add tuberemove, , endtube
            tuberemove = tubes(starttube)
            tubes.Remove starttube
            tuberemove(tempx) = ballcolor
            tubes.Add tuberemove, , starttube
            
        End If
    Next endtube
    Next starttube
    
End Property
Private Function isvalid(starttube As Integer, endtube As Integer, rws As Integer) As Boolean
    
    Dim ballcolor As String
    
    If starttube = endtube Then
        isvalid = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If tubes(starttube)(rws) = "x" Or tubes(endtube)(0) <> "x" Then
        isvalid = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For tempx = 0 To rws
        If tubes(starttube)(tempx) <> "x" Then
            ballcolor = tubes(starttube)(tempx)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tempx
    
    For tempy = 0 To rws - 1
        If tubes(endtube)(tempy + 1) <> "x" Then
            If tubes(endtube)(tempy + 1) <> ballcolor Then
                isvalid = False
                Exit Function
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next tempy
    
    isvalid = True

End Function
Property Let ordered(current As Variant)

    Dim rws As Integer
    Dim clms As Integer
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim focus() As Variant
    
    rws = UBound(current, 2)
    clms = UBound(current, 1)
    
    For y = 0 To clms
        ReDim focus(rws)
        For x = 0 To rws
            focus(x) = current(y, x)
        Next x
        tubes.Add focus
    Next y
    
    alphaorder = alphabetize(rws, clms)
    paststates.Add alphaorder
    
End Property
Private Function alphabetize(rws As Integer, clms As Integer) As String

    Dim alphax
    Dim order() As Variant
    Dim hold() As Variant
    Dim newhold() As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim level As Integer
    Dim done1, done2 As Boolean
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim symbolhold As Integer
    
    ReDim alphax(16)
    
    alphax = Array("x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p")
    
    ReDim order(clms)
    ReDim hold(rws)
    ReDim newhold(rws)
    
    For y = 0 To clms
        order(y) = y
    Next y
    
    done1 = False
    
    For y = 1 To clms
        For count = 0 To clms - y
            level = 0
nextsize:
            done2 = False
            For x = 0 To UBound(alphax, 1)
                If done1 = False Then
                    If tubes(order(count) + 1)(level) = alphax(x) Then
                        hold(level) = x
                        done1 = True
                    End If
                End If
                If done2 = False Then
                    If tubes(order(count + 1) + 1)(level) = alphax(x) Then
                        newhold(level) = x
                        done2 = True
                    End If
                End If
                If done1 And done2 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next x
            
            Select Case hold(level)
                Case Is < newhold(level)
                    For x = 0 To level
                        hold(x) = newhold(x)
                    Next x
                    
                Case Is > newhold(level)
                    symbolhold = order(count + 1)
                    order(count + 1) = order(count)
                    order(count) = symbolhold
                    
                Case Is = newhold(level)
                    If level < rws Then
                        level = level + 1
                        done1 = False
                        GoTo nextsize
                    End If

            End Select
            
        Next count
        done1 = False
    Next y
          
    For y = 0 To clms
        For x = 0 To rws
            alphabetize = alphabetize + tubes(order(y) + 1)(x)
        Next x
    Next y
End Function
```

Starting in range B2 I have various letters representing the color of the ball there. `x` is used to denote an empty space so the last 2 columns are just `x`.

If you go put a breakpoint at the alphaorder part in the ordered property and check the `tubes(1)` it shows an `x` in the first position and `tubes(10)` has an a in the last position which isn't supposed to happen until during the moves property which has not been called yet. On top of that the moves property is supposed to undo the change.

Again thank you for any help.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you created a [mcve] that others could experiment with. All you have given us are code fragments without a context to run them in.

Comment: I added my code. I'm not sure what is causing the issue in the class, so I included the whole thing. I'm sure most of it is unrelated to the problem but I'm so lost that I'm not sure what to even remove. However the test sub does reproduce the issue. So hopefully that helps.

Comment: `I thought maybe that since it is a class that VBA is trying to prepare the other properties when called` - no, but since you've added your class instance to the locals window, the debugger [will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982582/office-vba-when-are-properties-processed#comment118776367_66982582) call all its Property Gets to display what they return. If your Property Gets change the state of the object, they should really be methods, not properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office VBA: When are Properties processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66982582/11683)

Comment: I'm not sure if it does. I'm confused about why exactly the puzzle completes a move before I've even begun doing that. In your comment you linked you said that there is no functional difference between properties and methods. So is the problem being caused BECAUSE I am debugging it? Because everything works as intended if I stop it during the for loop.

Comment: Like specifically explained in the comment, it's because you have added it to the watch window, not because you are debugging it. Try debugging without watch windows. There is no functional difference between how properties and methods are implemented, but the watch window knows to not call methods.

Comment: @GSerg I see what you mean. I changed the Property Get Moves ( ) to Public Function Moves ( ) and that fixed it. However, I'm confused about why 1. Moves ( ) does not complete. Like it is supposed to undo the change, and it does when I was testing it yesterday. And 2. Why it executes at Y=9.